# Ningún módulo llamado pip._vendor

Tags: python, pip

Acabo de crear un entorno virtual porque faltaba uno para probar un repositorio de python. Parecía que le faltaba un módulo :

```
(env) mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/Rasa_tutorial/Weatherbot_Tutorial/Full Code [Latest release of Rasa NLU and Rasa Core]$ python train_online.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_online.py", line 8, in <module>
    from rasa_core.agent import Agent
ImportError: No module named 'rasa_core'
```

Pero cuando intenté descargar el modulo que faltaba tuve este famoso error con pip._vendor ...

```
(env) mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/Rasa_tutorial/Weatherbot_Tutorial/Full Code [Latest release of Rasa NLU and Rasa Core]$ python -m pip install rasa_nlu
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 133, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "/home/mike/Programing/Rasa_tutorial/Weatherbot_Tutorial/Full Code [Latest release of Rasa NLU and Rasa Core]/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pip.exceptions import InstallationError, CommandError, PipError
  File "/home/mike/Programing/Rasa_tutorial/Weatherbot_Tutorial/Full Code [Latest release of Rasa NLU and Rasa Core]/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/exceptions.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.six import iteritems
ImportError: No module named 'pip._vendor.six'
```

sin embargo, eso no parece ser un nuevo error. Leo [aquí](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/6719) por un error similiar, `No module named 'pip._vendor.requests.adapters'`, que forzar una reinstalación con "conda install pip -f" solucionó el problema. Sin embargo falta conda en este entorno :

```
(env) mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/Rasa_tutorial/Weatherbot_Tutorial/Full Code [Latest release of Rasa NLU and Rasa Core]$ conda install pip -f
conda: command not found
```

Y cuando instalolo le dice :

```
$ bash Anaconda-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
...
ERROR: File or directory already exists: '/home/mike/anaconda3'
If you want to update an existing installation, use the -u option.
```